# Why if L and ¬L (Complement of L) are turing-recognized both are turing-decidable?

Tags: turing-machines

I can't understand this theorem:
If both L and L complement are turing-recognized, both are turing-decidable

Proof:

- w is M input
- if w ∈ L then M1 accepts w and M accepts w
- if w ∉ L then M2 accepts w and M rejects w

M is a TM containing M1 and M2.

Comment: What didn't you understand in the proof or in the theorem?

Comment: I don't understand how there is no possibility of both M1 and M2 not deciding and then M executing forever.

Comment: Since every $x$ must be either in $L$ or not in $L$, then $x\in L(M_1)$ or $x \in L(M_2)$. Therefore, one of them must halt at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain it in simpler terms.

If $L$ is Turing recognizable, there exists a TM $M_1$ that halts and accepts any input string $w \in L$. It is not guaranteed to halt on any input string $w \notin L$.

If $\bar{L}$ is Turing recognizable, there exists a TM $M_2$ that halts and accepts any input string $w \notin L$. Similarly to above, $M_2$ is not guaranteed to halt on any input string $w \in L$.

Now, for every $w$ we have two options: either $w \in L$ or $w \notin L$. Therefore for any input string $w$, exactly one of these machines will halt and accept. This allows us to construct the decider described in you proof. Create a machine $M$ that simulates $M_1$ and $M_2$. With $w$ as input, accept $w$ if $M_1$ accepts, reject if $M_2$ accepts. This machine is a decider for $L$ and therefore $L$ is decidable.

To prove $\bar{L}$ decidable as well, you could apply the same logic, but it is sufficient to point out that decidable languages are closed under complement.